# Schedule Job with custom Trigger and params

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am using the Grails Quartz plugin and want to schedule my jobs with a programmatically-created Trigger. I do not know beforehand what the execution interval will be. I want the job to execute indefinitely.

[The docs give some examples](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz) of how to schedule/trigger jobs:

> == Dynamic Jobs Scheduling ==
>
> Starting from 0.4.1 version you have the ability to schedule job executions dynamically.
>
> These methods are available:
>
> - `MyJob.schedule(String cronExpression, Map params?)` creates cron trigger;
> - `MyJob.schedule(Long repeatInterval, Integer repeatCount?, Map params?)` creates simple trigger: repeats job repeatCount+1 times with delay of repeatInterval milliseconds;
> - `MyJob.schedule(Date scheduleDate, Map params?)` schedules one job execution to the specific date;
> - `MyJob.schedule(Trigger trigger)` schedules job's execution with a custom trigger;
> - `MyJob.triggerNow(Map params?)` force immediate execution of the job.
>
>   Each method (except the one for custom trigger) takes optional 'params' argument. You can use it to pass some data to your job and then access it from the job.

Grails Version 1.3.7
Quartz Plugin version 0.4.2

So, why does the `MyJob.schedule(Trigger trigger)` not take params? And, how can I achieve what I want, using a custom trigger and a map or params for the Job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look [where these methods are defined](https://github.com/nebolsin/grails-quartz/blob/master/QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy#L123) in the [Quartz plugin sourcecode](https://github.com/nebolsin/grails-quartz), you can see that all of the functions that take `Map params` are wrappers which create a `Trigger` and then fire it off to the scheduler.

The `MyJob.schedule(Trigger trigger)` method, just fires off the trigger you pass it, so it is up to you to add your params into the Triggers `jobDataMap` property before you call this method, ie:

```
trigger.jobDataMap.putAll [foo:"It Works!"]
MyJob.schedule( trigger )
```

Comment: I am getting a no property exception... do i have to import something?

Answer (score 1):

tim answer is correct, here is little bit updation.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .startNow()
                .withIdentity("triggerName", "groupName")
                .withSchedule(
                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                .withIntervalInSeconds(5000).repeatForever()
                ).build();
        trigger.jobDataMap.putAll([foo:"bar"])
        MyJob.schedule(trigger)
```